# How deobfuscate a javascript variable obfuscated to hexadecimal representation?

Tags: javascript, hex, deobfuscation

I have the following code that probably was obfuscated using [*this site*](https://obfuscator.io/).

I want to know if there is a way to revert this code to original version before obfuscation.

```
 var _0x25e019 = _0x3409['uaQTyc'][_0x2ed933];
    if (_0x25e019 === undefined) {
        _0x3e0f4c = _0x3409['SqQRqd'](_0x3e0f4c);
        _0x3409['uaQTyc'][_0x2ed933] = _0x3e0f4c;
    } else {
        _0x3e0f4c = _0x25e019;
    }
    return _0x3e0f4c;
};
```

Comment: No, there is not, and that's deliberate.

Comment: Obfuscated? Makes perfect sense to me. :)

Comment: Try to find variables where you can identify the sense, them give them names and work through the whole code like that

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing can be done except waste a lot of time jumping breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can’t.**

According to [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/),

> **Can I recover the original source code from the obfuscated one?**
>
> No, it's impossible to revert the obfuscated code back to your original code, so keep the original safe.

Answer (score 1):

The browser does it for you. See it here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can revert the code manually. Most obfuscators use Hexadecimal to encrypt the Js code. There must a way around to revert it since every browser can read and understand the obfuscated code.

Comment: Please post descriptive answer.